# C++ beginner exercises: grading program

Tags: c++, beginner

I finished the grading exercise from this [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/) of beginner c++ exercises. I have a (probably unfounded) dislike of if elses to dispatch a grade to a note so contrarily to [this similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67276/optimizing-simple-c-grading-program) I implemented a vector of tuples to which I compare the received note. After completion, I realized that it probably amounts to mostly the same thing, if not worse (I am still comparing the value with an if).

I looking for any feedback, but possibly something about:

- Is the vector of tuple an unnecessary overhead over the simple if/else?
- Is it actually *slower*, or does compilation optimizes execution?
- In this case it probably doesn't matter because the grade set is small, but is this approach considered a good/correct practice if we were to have a bigger set?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

char dispatchGrade(int grade) {
    vector<tuple<int, char>> fork {
            tuple<int, char> {90, 'A'},
            tuple<int, char> {80, 'B'},
            tuple<int, char> {70, 'C'},
            tuple<int, char> {60, 'D'},
            tuple<int, char> {0, 'E'},
    };
    for (vector<tuple<int, char>>::size_type i = 0; i != fork.size(); i++) {
        if (grade >= get<0>(fork[i])) {
            return get<1>(fork[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int grade;
    char note;
    cout << "Hello, World! enter your grade:" << endl;
    cin >> grade;
    if (!cin.fail() && grade > -1 && grade < 101) {
        cout << "That is a valid grade. ";
        note = dispatchGrade(grade);
        cout << "That grade is good for a " << note << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "That is not a valid grade." << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(grades)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(grades ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: How is E a grade? I think you mean F.

Comment: @T145 I was under the impression that E was the letter that follows D, but maybe schools don't use it, I don't know about that ;) Oh, but I see the exercise really uses F.

Comment: When we were at school we had grades A-E. Think that is pretty normal. Anything under a C was a fail and need to be re-taken. Though a C was less than 70% at our school.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Code Review:

```
grade > -1 && grade < 101
```

That's fine for integers. But you have to consider that somebody can come along behind you and modify your types sometime in the future. If I changed the type of grade to float (not an unreasonable change). Then a grade of `-.05` becomes valid. I would change this to be:

grade >= 0 && grade <= 100

```
!cin.fail()
```

Checking the state of the file manually is basically never correct (its an anti-pattern). Also this case is also wrong as `fail()` does not check for end of file, so you could have hit end of file not read anything into grade.

A better check is:

```
cin.good();
```

But the more usual check is

```
cin  // If used in a boolean context (like an if) it will be converted
     // to a boolean based on the call to good.


if (cin && grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)
```

But even this is not usual. Usually you check the result of the read operation by placing the read into the if statement.

```
if (cin >> grade && grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)
```

Note: the `operator>>` returns a a reference to the stream, so this is functionally the same as the line above. But it imparts more information.

What you are saying here is: `if the read works and the grade is in the range [0..100]` we succeeded.

Looking at your dispatch. You have a structure that is the same every time you call.

```
vector<tuple<int, char>> fork {
        tuple<int, char> {90, 'A'},
        tuple<int, char> {80, 'B'},
        tuple<int, char> {70, 'C'},
        tuple<int, char> {60, 'D'},
        tuple<int, char> {0, 'E'},
};
```

Since this is never modified it should be marked `const`. Also since you really only want to build the structure once just mark it `static` that way you only build the structure on the first call. Also there is a convenience function called make_tuple

```
static const vector<tuple<int, char>> fork
{
        make_tuple(90, 'A'),
        make_tuple(80, 'B'),
        make_tuple(70, 'C'),
        make_tuple(60, 'D'),
        make_tuple(0,  'E')
};
```

This loop is a bit C-Like (though it works).

```
for (vector<tuple<int, char>>::size_type i = 0; i != fork.size(); i++)
```

Though I would have used some typedefs to make it more readable:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, char>  MarkRange;
typedef std::vector<MarkRange> MarkSet;
for (MarkSet::size_type i = 0; i != fork.size(); ++i)  // prefer pre-increment
```

If you were using C++03 then I would be using iterators:

```
for (MarkSet::const_iterator i = fork.begin(); i != fork.end(); ++i)
```

But since C++11 we have had range based for

```
for (auto const& mark : fork)
```

Note:

```
// Since C++11 prefer `using` over typedef
using MarkRange = std::tuple<int, char>;
using MarkSet   = std::vector<MarkRange>;
```

Using `std::endl` is not a good idea. Prefer `"\n"`. The difference is that `endl` flushes the stream.  Flushing is usually always wrong. The streams will flush themselves at appropriate times let the code do its work.

Note: The most common complaint about C++ stream is that they are slower than C stream. This is usually down to inappropriate calls to flush that significantly degrades performance when done incorrectly (and manually is usually always incorrect).

### Questions:

> Is the vector of tuple an unnecessary overhead over the simple if/else?

I like it. Its called `Data Driven` programing (where the code uses data to define its structure). This is usually considered best practice.

> Is it actually slower, or does compilation optimizes execution?

I doubt you could measure the difference.
But if it is important then you should measure it.
People will always have opinions on this; they are not relevant. The only thing that matters is data. **BUT** it only matters if this is important. Normally I would consider more expressive readable code more important. This code is readable and easy to update (I could even put the data into a config file that is modified seprately).

> In this case it probably doesn't matter because the grade set is small, but is this approach considered a good/correct practice if we were to have a bigger set?

Even in bigger list this seems like a better idea.

Comment: A `std::array` instead of a `std::vector` can even be a `constexpr`.

Comment: A concrete exemple of how to use typedef really connected the dots over doubts I've been having for some time. Thanks for your detailed review!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Note. Since C++11 it is better to use `using` rather than `typedef`. The using as a typedef is much more powerful as you can also template the using. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: @Loki: `using` is not "better" than `typedef`, it is similar but different.  Sometimes those differences are advantageous, sometimes they are crippling.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I still use typedef a lot (out of habit). I am trying to change that habit into using `using`. But I would love to understand when using is not the correct way. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: @Rakete1111 It does matter a lot with performance as that would make it terrible. Sorry sarcasm based on the absurd (and untrue) observation that a vector of pairs is a map!!!!!

Comment: @Loki Oh woops, sorry. I have to stop commenting on posts just after I wake up :/